# Elegant way to testing the Services/Service Containers in Symfony3 with PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, containers, symfony

I'm learning recently about the **Symfony 3** framework and **Dependency Injection**.

I would like you to help me solve my doubts about the method of testing **Services** in Symfony 3 using **PHPUnit**. I have some concerns how to do it right way.

Lets make an example of **Service** class:

```
// src/AppBundle/Services/MathService.php
namespace AppBundle\Services;

class MathService
{
    public function subtract($a, $b)
    {
        return $a - $b;
    }
}
```

I see that usually the UnitTest classes in Symfony tests the **Controllers**.

But what can I test independent classes like **Services** (which have business logic included for example) instead of **Controllers** ?

I know there are at least 2 ways to do it:

---

**1.** Create a Test Class which extends the **`PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`** and **create** the object of Service **inside some methods** or **constructor** in this Test Class (exactly like in Symfony docs about [testing](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html))

```
// tests/AppBundle/Services/MathTest.php
namespace Tests\AppBundle\Services;

use AppBundle\Services\MathService;

class MathTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $math;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->math = new MathService();
    }

    public function testSubtract()
    {
        $result = $this->math->subtract(5, 3);
        $this->assertEquals(2, $result);
    }
}
```

---

**2.** Make our Service class as a **Service Container** using Dependency injection. Then create a Test Class which extends the **`KernelTestCase`** to get access to the Kernel. It will give us ability to **inject our Service using Container** from Kernel (based on Symfony docs about [testing Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/master/testing/doctrine.html)).

Configuration of Service Container:

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    app.math:
        class: AppBundle\Services\MathService
```

Now our **Test Class** will looks like:

```
// tests/AppBundle/Services/MathTest.php
namespace Tests\AppBundle\Services;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;

class MathTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    private $math;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        self::bootKernel();

        $this->math = static::$kernel
            ->getContainer()
            ->get('app.math');
    }

    public function testSubtract()
    {
        $result = $this->math->subtract(5, 3);
        $this->assertEquals(2, $result);
    }
}
```

There are benefits when we choose this way.

Firstly we have access to our **Service Container** in *controllers* and *tests* through **Dependency Injection**.

Secondly - if in the future we want to change the **location** of *Service class* or change the **name** of class - compared with **1.** case - we can avoid changes in many files, because we will change path/name at least in  **`services.yml`** file.

---

My questions:

#### Are there another ways to test Service class in Symfony 3 ? Which way is better and should be used?

Comment: "I see that usually the UnitTest classes in Symfony tests the Controllers." However did you come to such a strange conclusion?  Stop overthinking the problem and just use your first approach.  And make sure you understand the difference between a unit test and a functional test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATED 2018 with tricky Symfony 3.4/4.0 solution.**

**This approach [with all its pros/cons is described in this post with code examples](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2018/05/17/how-to-test-private-services-in-symfony/#2-in-symfony-4-1-standalone-or-symfony-3-4-4-0).**

---

The best solution to access private services is to add **a Compiler Pass that makes all services public for tests**.

### 1. Update Kernel

```
 use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
+use Symplify\PackageBuilder\DependencyInjection\CompilerPass\PublicForTestsCompilerPass;

 final class AppKernel extends Kernel
 {
     protected function build(ContainerBuilder $containerBuilder): void
     {
         $containerBuilder->addCompilerPass('...');
+        $containerBuilder->addCompilerPass(new PublicForTestsCompilerPass());
     }
 }
```

### 2. Require or create own Compiler Pass

Where `PublicForTestsCompilerPass` looks like:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

final class PublicForTestsCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $containerBuilder): void
    {
        if (! $this->isPHPUnit()) {
            return;
        }

        foreach ($containerBuilder->getDefinitions() as $definition) {
            $definition->setPublic(true);
        }

        foreach ($containerBuilder->getAliases() as $definition) {
            $definition->setPublic(true);
        }
    }

    private function isPHPUnit(): bool
    {
        // defined by PHPUnit
        return defined('PHPUNIT_COMPOSER_INSTALL') || defined('__PHPUNIT_PHAR__');
    }
}
```

To use this class, just add the package by:

```
composer require symplify/package-builder
```

But of course, the better way is to use own class, that meets your needs (you migt Behat for tests etc.).

**Then all your tests will keep working as expected!**